# How RocksDBStateBackend in Flink spills data to disk?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As far as I know, RocksDBStateBackend spills data to disk if memory pressure occurs, but I can't find where this spill op happens, can some body help find this piece of source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink's RocksDBStateBackend uses [RocksDB](https://rocksdb.org/) to store state. RocksDB is an embedded disk-based key-value store. Flink's state backend simply uses RocksDB's API for writing and reading and RocksDB puts the data on the disk. The code you are looking for is in RocksDB, not in Flink.

Comment: Thanks very much, got it now.